# How to make a folder/directory undeletable/unremovable for a user but still writable

Tags: linux, bash, sh, file-permissions

This is needed for a case when it is necessary to create a folder in home directory of a user, to allow user read/write/remove files in the folder, but not allow to remove the folder itself (considering a regular user and not a sudoer).

In my case (i.e. RedHat) it was not enough just to put a file with root rights inside user`s folder, because the user owns the folder.
In my case if a user owns (or has all permissions on) a folder, he can remove it even with root file or empty folder inside.

I have made quite a number of experiments including playing with `chown` and permissions like 400, 000, o+t, 1775 etc. Initially  I did not want to use `chattr`.

Meanwhile I have found a solution, which I share as an answer below; a variant that suits my needs so far.

Comment: I edited question and your answer in parallel, to make a separated question/answer pair. The edit is a bit more extensive than I usually do. Let me know if you think it is beyond your intentions. In that case feel free to roll back and I will apologize.

Comment: @Yunnosch I think everything is ok, you do great job helping to clarify the point. Thank you.

Comment: In order to remove a directory, one must have permission to write to the parent directory. So, remove that permission from the user in question, and they won't be able to remove the sub-directory...

Comment: @twalberg This is the point in my situation: user must have ability to write into the directory (like I have written in the title). Moreover, in my case it must be a directory with user`s rights.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution I found myself.
Basically it uses the fact that when root subfolder is not empty, the user cannot remove it anymore.

In the below example superuser (root) each time creates (if does not exist already) a folder with user rights in user`s home directory, then puts inside a folder with root rights (if does not exist already), and inside that root folder puts a file with root rights.

```
## prepare directory for the external configuration
EXT_CONFIG_PATH="~user/.EXT_CONFIG"
mkdir -p ${EXT_CONFIG_PATH}
chown user:user ${EXT_CONFIG_PATH}
chmod 555 ${EXT_CONFIG_PATH}
mkdir -p ${EXT_CONFIG_PATH}/.rootguard
chmod o+t ${EXT_CONFIG_PATH}/.rootguard
touch ${EXT_CONFIG_PATH}/.rootguard/.rootguard
chmod 400 ~user/.EXT_CONFIG/.rootguard/.rootguard
```

Comment: Why is it ok/sufficient to put a folder with a file, but not a file? Asking and answering yourself is OK, even potentially appreciated. But you still have to explain your solution, not only what is done but also why and how it solved the problem. Especially if it could be read as contradicting the stated requirements of the problem.

Comment: In my case it was not enough to put only a root file inside because it is a user folder. If I remember correctly, it is a Linux policy (cannot say for sure for other distros / versions though) that if a user owns (or has all permissions on) a folder, he can remove it even with root file or empty folder inside. When root subfolder is not empty he cannot remove it anymore.

Comment: Interesting background information. I recommend to edit that into the question. In my opinion the question gets "useful and researched" then (but not so much as it is...). Maybe you can even quote something on this?

Comment: @Yunnosch Got it. Thanks.

Comment: An alternative without the need for a directory would be just add `chattr +i` to the  `.rootguard`-file. This overrides the policy of a user being allowed to delete any file from a directory he owns.